# Edittext in each listitem of a listview is hidden by softkeyboard

Tags: android, layout, android-manifest, android-softkeyboard

I have an EditText in each row of listview. When I tap the EditText the softkeyboard pops up as expected while the listview slides up placing the EditText above the keyboard. However, once I begin typing, the ListView slides back down and the EditText is now behind the softkeyboard obstructing the view of the typing. I am still able to type, but the EditText is covered by the softkeyboard.

How can I keep the EditText visible above the keyboard?

Comment: Did you try using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"` for edittext?

Comment: Yes i have try both adjustResize and adjustPan

Comment: This issue is existing in Samsumg Tab 3 . I rechecking multiple times with adjustpan and adjustResize. but still exist.

Answer (score 1):

Just add This to your manifest in activity tag:

```
   <activity           
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden" >
    </activity>
```

and remove request focus from edittext.

## OR

if this is not working then you have to make your view(layout) scrollable and when the EditText view gets focus manually scroll the ScrollView. and in case of listview you have to disbale parent scroll of listview when you touch on listview,which is scrollview. mostly this problem is with the samsung devices, I think it's an issue with their touchwiz interface. there are two options now.

```
1). add some content in your inflator and make them invisible.so that it moves up the edittext.
2).i think  if you make your action bar custom(remove and using a layout of fixed height) then it will solve your issue.
```

## if

you already remove your action bat by giving a theme fullscreen in manifest file,then you can never use adjustresize property, now to use adjust resize property you have to put your layout in scrollview.only this is the solution.please check all the info.may be this will help you.

Comment: I have tried same but still issue exist in Samsung Tab 3. But in HCL it workings fine.

Comment: giv a try with adjustpan|adjustresize. and let me know

Comment: i tried with both.adjustpan and adjustresize. still same result.I think list scroll making it critical.

Comment: Thanks and (+1) for good suggestion and support .

Comment: you are welcome dude..please give a try and let me know.